# Java: printing an array without Arrays.toString

Tags: java, arrays

```
public String[] geefAlleTemplateNamen(String[][] templateLijst){
    String[] lijst = new String[templateLijst.length];
    for(int i = 0; i < templateLijst.length; i++){
        lijst[i] = templateLijst[i][0];
    }
return lijst;
}
```

The code above returns an array 'lijst'.

```
System.out.println(geefAlleTemplateNamen(templateLijst));
```

With this piece of code I tried to print that array, but it prints the location of the array. I know this can be solved by importing Java.util.Arrays, but I am not allowed to do this (school project), is there any way to solve this?

Thank you!

Comment: Iterate through the elements and print them out.

Comment: And the JDK is open source. You can see how this [method](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/Arrays.java#Arrays.toString%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29) is implemented and inspire yourself.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Simplest way to print an array in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/409784/simplest-way-to-print-an-array-in-java)  Look at the solutions near the bottom (using for loops and for each loops)

Answer (score 3):

The simplest and easiest way to do this is to throw your array into a for loop.

```
for (int i = 0; i < lijst.length; i++) { System.out.println(lijst[i]); }
```

Printing the array itself should and will print its memory location, and you'll want to access each member of the array individually instead.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest solution would be,

```
for(String s: lijst)
{
    System.out.println(s);
}
```